# how to create a custom checkbox in c# which has an outlined text

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

I want to have a checkbox that has an outline to it's text.
I searched for ways to do it and found none.
Can anyone help?

Thanks

edit:

I use winforms, and i really couldn't find any example of this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? do you have any examples or code to show?

Comment: Your questions is too broad, you don't even mention the technology, WinForms, WPF etc..

Comment: Web forms? MVC razor pages? WPF? WinForms? Something else?

Comment: There are plenty of examples, just use your favourite search engine - but remember to include in what type of environment you want to create a custom checkbox (Web, WPF, Winforms, etc.)

Comment: edited my post. i haven't tried much cause i don't know where to start really. i also have no code that could help here.

Comment: Are you looking for styled text or border around the text ? You need to mention what exactly you want and explain it in as detail as possible.

Comment: sorry' i thought it was clear. i'm looking for a way to put a border around the text itself.